# Angular JS for Frontend Development?

Tags: angularjs, frontend

I wanted to know if Angular JS is a good choice for developing in frontend
websites. Duo to this, I read Angular is a good alternative for j-query, 
no DOM manipulation etc - but i also read it is used for webapps like
JSP-Apps. So is it also usable and comfortable in "traditional" websites development - like for business customers with 5-10 subsites ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

angularjs is great. its best feature is the data binding.

in jquery you get data and then update the view - a 2 step process

in angular you get data and angular auto updates the view - a 1 step process

comes with a load of helpers too. uses promises heavily, which are similar to callbacks but promise chains can be flattened unlike callback chains.

promises also allow for failure handlers.

due to its routing it is great for making large complex online apps (single pages apps - SPAs)